# Nested li element overlaps parent li

Tags: angularjs, html, css, angular-ng-if

I have a nested list element as a menu. When I click on an item, I want the list to expand and the inner list to show up. But the inner li item (sub-menu item 1)overlaps the parent li (Menu item 2).

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul class="no-list-style">
        <li class="menu-item" ng-click="selectedAction = 1">Menu Item 1
            <ul class="no-list-style" ng-if="selectedAction == 1">
                <li class="sub-menu-item">Sub-menu item 1</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">Menu item 2</li>
        <li class="menu-item">Menu item 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My CSS looks like this:

```
.no-list-style {
    padding: 0;
}
.menu-item {
    height: 30px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin: 0;
}
.sub-menu-item {
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

If I don't use position absolute for css class sub-menu-item, both texts in sub-menu item 1 and menu item 2 overlap.

I want the sub-menu item to get inserted into the vertical menu, moving the menu item 2 down.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide a plunker.

Comment: Impossible to understand what your expected visual behavior is from your description alone

Answer (score 0):

```js
function submenuappear() {
  document.getElementById("sub-menu-item").style.marginLeft =  "0";
  document.getElementById("menu-item2").style.marginTop =  "0";
  }

function submenudisappear() {
  document.getElementById("sub-menu-item").style.marginLeft =  "-300px";
  document.getElementById("menu-item2").style.marginTop =  "-20px";
  }

function submenudisappear() {
  document.getElementById("sub-menu-item").style.marginLeft =  "-300px";
  document.getElementById("menu-item2").style.marginTop =  "-20px";
  }
```

```css
#sub-menu-item {
    margin-left: -300px;
}

#menu-item2 {
  margin-top: -20px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="menu">
    <ul class="no-list-style">
        <li onclick="submenuappear()"class="menu-item" ng-click="selectedAction = 1">Menu Item 1
            <ul class="no-list-style" ng-if="selectedAction == 1">
                <li id="sub-menu-item">Sub-menu item 1</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li onclick="submenudisappear()" id="menu-item2">Menu item 2</li>
        <li onclick="submenudisappear()"id="menu-item3">Menu item 3</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have made a snippet. When you click on the first menu item, the submenu item will be visible in the navigationbar. Then when you click menu item 2 or 3 the submenuitem will disappear again. Hope that this is what you are looking for.

Comment: why would you ever put `onclick` into an angular app?

Comment: What do you mean and why not? @charlietfl

Comment: Oh okay well i thought it was just normal javascript